# How to connect smart phone and PC for java programming?

Tags: java, smartphone

Is there any way to connect smart phone and PC for java programming.i mean can i code same project using smart phone and PC?

Comment: What do you mean by connect? What's the expected result?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, as it not really clear what is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know If I understand your question. But this link should be helpful. It is focused on Using Hardware Devices in context of Android development.

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Next time, give greater care when you create the question.